# Function does not seem to run in php functions

Tags: php

I have a `functions.php` file where I have a `check_login` function, this function is just supposed to check if the session variables have been set on every page load,then it should just do nothing, but at this moment it looks like it does not execute the function.

Am I doing something wrong?

I have added code to allow me to see which side of the if statement executes, but it does not echo either values.

Index page:

```
require_once 'functions/functions.php';

check_login;
```

functions.php:

```
<?

function check_login(){
    session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION['user_id']) and ($_SESSION['user_id'] != '')and ($_SESSION['user_id'] != NULL)){
        echo '<p>Logged in</p>';

    }else{
        echo '<p>Not Logged in</p>';
        header("Location: login.php");
    }
}   
?>
```

Comment: try put `check_login();` instead of check_login;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

call your function with round brackets

```
require_once 'functions/functions.php';

check_login();
```

Answer (score 3):

To call a function you should use parenthesis `()`. And while your project is in development, please add this line to track the errors. `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

this should be

```
check_login();
```

instead of

```
check_login;
```

Thus,

```
require_once 'functions/functions.php';
check_login();
```

functions.php:

```
<?

function check_login(){
    session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION['user_id']) and ($_SESSION['user_id'] != '')and ($_SESSION['user_id'] != NULL)){
        echo '<p>Logged in</p>';

    }else{
        echo '<p>Not Logged in</p>';
        header("Location: login.php");
    }
}   
?>
```

For more reference see [this](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php)

Answer (score 3):

Change from

```
check_login;
```

To

```
check_login();
```

Answer (score 2):

`check_login` should be `check_login()`.

And also

```
if (isset($_SESSION['user_id']) and ($_SESSION['user_id'] != '')and ($_SESSION['user_id'] != NULL))
```

Can be condensed into this

```
if (!empty($_SESSION['user_id']))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you call a function, you should use `()` after the function name. Try this:

```
check_login();
```

instead of:

```
check_login;
```

Answer (score 1):

use `()` before call function :-

```
require_once 'functions/functions.php';
check_login();
```

or `session_start` must be on first line :-

```
<?php
session_start();
function check_login(){    
    if (isset($_SESSION['user_id']) and ($_SESSION['user_id'] != '') and  ($_SESSION['user_id'] != NULL)) {
        echo '<p>Logged in</p>';
    } else {
        echo '<p>Not Logged in</p>';
        header("Location: login.php");
    }
}   
?>
```